# Is there any issues using an unsupported water cooler for my socket type? LGA1151 to LGA1700

Tags: cpu, cooling

I upgraded my PC recently from a i7 7700k (LGA1151) to i7 12700k (LGA1700), and to my stupidity surprise, the new water cooler I got doesn't fit in my case.
So I tried my old water cooler, a Corsair H105 Hydro, and surprisingly it did fit my motherboard/CPU.

My question is does the area/surface might make it inefficient since the CPUs are of different size and I'll have issues later on, or was it just luck they fit and as long as they're touching it'll be fine?

Comment: I believe the compatibility is mostly about the mounting mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I would contact Corsair, and ask if there's an adaptor kit to mount a H105 to an LGA1700 socket. You MIGHT get good contact with different stand-offs, but if you don't, you'll smoke your CPU. It's not worth the risk, imho.